# question related to UITextview

Tags: iphone

I have 1 question I have 1 UITextview,
now,when i click on UITextview and enter text at that time i want that UIScrollview scrolls upwards as line by line goes down of UITextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement

```
UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
```

delegate Method, inside it adjust UIScrollview as per your requirement...